# How from convergence of $\sum_{n=N+1}^{m+1}a_{n}$ conclude that $\sum_{n=N}^{m}a_{n}$ is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I tried to prove Kummer's test (I already learned the proof, but just wanted to prove again to make sure that I know what theorems/tests have been used).

---

Let $\left\{a_{n}\right\}_{n\ge N}\ ,\left\{b_{n}\right\}_{n\ge N}$ be two positive real sequences , define: $$K_{n}:=b_{n}\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}-b_{n+1}$$

Then:

- $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges if there exist $r>0$ and positive natural number $N$ such that $r\le K_{n}$ for all $n\ge N$
- $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ diverges if $K_{n}\le0$ for all $n\ge N$  and $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{b_{n}}$ diverges.

Proof:

Assume there exist a positive number $r$ and $N \in \mathbb N^{+}$ such that $0<r\le K_{n}$ for all $n\ge N$ , it follows:

$$0<ra_{n+1}\le b_{n}a_{n}-b_{n+1}a_{n+1}$$

So $\left\{a_{n}b_{n}\right\}_{n\ge N}$ is a monotone decreasing sequence wich is bounded below by $0$ , since $a_{n}b_{n} >0$ for all $n\ge N$, implies the sequence is convergent,moreover:

$$\sum_{n=N}^{m}b_{n}a_{n}-b_{n+1}a_{n+1}=a_{N}b_{N}-b_{m+1}a_{m+1} \rightarrow a_{N}b_{N} -\rho $$$$\text{as} $$$$m \rightarrow \infty$$

Where $\rho \in \mathbb R ^{+}$, using comparison test implies that $\sum_{n=N}^{m}ra_{n+1}$ is convergent , and so does $\sum_{n=N+1}^{m+1}a_{n}=\sum_{n=N}^{m}a_{n}-a_{N}+a_{m+1}$

---

This is where I cannot continue, how from convergence of $\sum_{n=N+1}^{m+1}a_{n}$ conclude that $\sum_{n=N}^{m}a_{n}$ is convergent.

Comment: It's nice to see crab questions /homework questions without any kind of effort get lots of attention, but these questions get nothing.clearly earning reputation is what some people are characterized by .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=N}^{m}a_n&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\sum_{n=N+1}^{m+1}a_n+a_N-a_{m+1}\right)\\
&= a_N+\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=N+1}^{m+1}a_n-\lim_{m\to\infty}a_{m+1}
\end{align}$$
We know the first limit in the previous line exists, and $\lim_{m\to\infty}a_{m+1}=0$ since the series converges. Alternatively, you can do the summation from $N$ to $m-1$. That is, $\sum_{n=N}^{m-1}(b_na_n-b_{n+1}a_{n+1})$ converges as $m\to\infty$ which implies the convergence of $\sum_{n=N}^{m-1}a_{n+1}=\sum_{n=N+1}^ma_n$. Then, take limit as $m\to\infty$ in $\sum_{n=N}^ma_n=\sum_{n=N+1}^ma_n-a_N$.